# Send Receive JSON POST data PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a device where I execute this php file

```
$url = "https://xxxxx.com/raspberry/json.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA
{
  "Device": "102",
  "Status": "Power on",
}
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

The receiver file

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo $data;

$json = json_decode($data, true);

echo "Device: " . $json['Device'];
echo "Device: " . $json->Device;
```

print me

```
string(62) "{
  "Device": "125",
  "Status": "Power on",
}Device: Device: "
```

so why don't print me the single data? I expect it prints also the single element.
thanks

Comment: It is invalid JSON data due to the extra comma in `"Status": "Power on",` . So `json_decode` is  [returning `null`](https://3v4l.org/a2ZYe). Check the return value of `$json = json_decode()` or use `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`.

Comment: @WillB. thanks! If I deleted the comma it works. If I try this method it work also with comma
`
$jsonData = array(
    'Device' => '125',
    'password' => 'Power on',
);
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
`
So what is the best?
Thanks

Comment: Because the comma is allowed in the PHP array context which is effectively ignored during lexing, but not JSON textual context. To ensure proper encoding and avoid nuanced rules with the JSON text output, I suggest using the PHP array/object approach with `json_encode()`, such as `is_array($json) && array_key_exists('Device', $json)`

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct files.

```
// SEND DATA
$url = "https://xxxx.com/raspberry/json.php";

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'Device' => '125',
    'password' => 'Power on'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

and receive the data

```
// RECEIVE DATA
//Make sure that it is a POST request.
if (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0) {
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}

//Make sure that the content type of the POST request has been set to application/json
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if (strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0) {
    throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
}

//Receive the RAW post data.
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post data from JSON.
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);

//If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
if (!is_array($decoded)) {
    throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
}


// Access to the data
$element = $decoded['Device'];
echo "Device: " .$element;
```

*thanks to Will B.*